# Elements created with JavaScript are not showing up when infinite loop is running

Tags: javascript, html

I have elements created with document.appendChild();
I have an infinite loop which checks if a radio button is selected. If I run the webpage without the infinite loop, these elements show up fine, but if I run it with the infinite loop, the elements do not show up on the screen.

How do I go about fixing this issue?

Comment: why you need an infinite loop?

Comment: can you add your markup and js code

Comment: Don't use infinite loops.

Comment: I'm using an infinite loop to check if my radio buttons are selected. I'm guessing I'm doing it with the wrong approach though.

Comment: Find better solution, avoid infinite loops... You don't need infinite loop for checking radio button state...

Comment: In that case add an event listener or something. I think the current approach is not good.

Comment: I forgot to mention I was using an infinite loop to check if a radio button is pressed. The use of onclick completely flew over my head earlier, but since I'm using this instead it works fine. Thank you for the answers everyone.

Comment: @EdwardYang please edit your question and add that you're using the loop to check the state of radio buttons. That's an important fact.

Comment: Added. Sorry for the lack of information in my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a browser, the DOM rendering and javascript engine run in the same thread. Meaning an infinite loop will block the DOM from rendering.

You need to use a [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval) or [`requestAnimationFrame()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) to run your code asynchronously, giving the browser an opportunity to render the DOM.

**EDIT:** You said in the comments that you're using the infinite loop to check the state of radio buttons. That is unnecessary since the browser uses an event model. This means you can listen radio button `change` events and an event "handler" function can be called only when the state changes.

Comment: I'd +1 if I could since I did not know DOM rendering and JavaScript run on the same thread. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

if you have your infinite loop running, your script will never end running, it will keep stuck in the loop and your DOM won't render. As Soviut said, as the browser works in a single thread, even if you browser is multithreaded the running thread will make the tab to freeze. You can use his suggestions (nowadays, the browsers allow you to stop the script if a certain amount of time is reached), but I also read about workers on Javascript that may help you do your thing (I've never used it, but I will attach here the link to the resource).

Good luck

http://www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/tutorials/introducing-html-5-web-workers-bringing-multi-threading-to-javascript.html#fbid=61Sm3Bje2xn